# Proving that the unit sphere is a submanifold.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm trying to prove that the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-1$.

Let's define $g(x)=\|x\|^2$, then $S^{n-1}=g^{-1}(\{1\})$. It's easy to see that $Dg(x)$ has maximal rank, since for any element in the sphere is not zero, and hence it's surjective.

Now if I use the Submersion Theorem, for any $x^0 \in S^{n-1}$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x^0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $S^{n-1}\cap U$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold.

What I don't get is how from here we can deduce that $S^{n-1}$ is also a $C^\infty$ submanifold.

I was thinking of union of submanifolds being also a manifold, but for that it should suffice for the submanifolds to be disjoint, which I don't see to be able to guarantee...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @M10687 thanks for the links. But could you help for this specific method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion of the « submersion theorem » tells you precisely that $S^{n-1}$ is a manifold. Indeed, you can find around each $x_0\in S^{n-1}$ a small open set of $S^{n-1}$ that is diffeomorphic to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Otherwise, the [preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem) tells you that $g^{-1}(1)$ is a manifold, since the derivative of $g$ is surjective at all points of $g^{-1}(1)$.

Comment: Olivier. Thanks for the answer. The book I'm using states that it's the level set intersected with a neighbourhood of $x_0$ that is a submanifold... 

I'm trying how we can extend to the desired conclusion. ;)